# How to: Properly use PHP to encode data into JSON format, and request the data with jquery/ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, mysqli

I am trying to create an address book of sorts.

I can successfully connect to the database and insert data with a php script.

I have even managed to display json encoded data of my table rows, though I don't know if I am doing it right.

**What I am actually trying to accomplish:**

1. I would like to be able to make an ajax request for say, and ID, then get back all of that ID's corresponding data, (wrapped in Json - At least I think it needs to be..).
2. With the ajax script, I would like to be able to save the returned corresponding data to an input field in an html file.

I would also like to know if it would be better to try to return HTML to the ajax call, and input the data into the html input fields that way?

So far I am having limited success, but here is what I have so far...

**I have a DB connection script:**

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";
$db = "data_base";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

if($mysqli->connect_error) 
 die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());

return $mysqli;
```

**A mysql ISAM DB with the following columns:**

```
    id, user, pass, nickname, address, facebook, twitter, linkedin, youtube
    ID should be unique
    User is an index
    Pass is an index
    nickname is an index
    address is primary - though its possible that id should be...
    Facebook, Twitter, Linkedin, and Youtube are all indexes.
```

Note: I would be happy to change index, primary, etc as somebody sees fit...

**EDITED!**Now my query page:**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);
include 'db/dbcon.php';
//Start connection with SQL
$q = "SELECT * FROM `cfaddrbook` WHERE key = '111111'";
$res = $mysqli->query($q) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$q]");
$array = array(); // initialize
while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
$array[] = array(
'key' => $row[0],
'username' => $row[1],
// ... continue like this
);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
$res->free();
$mysqli->close();
```

Now, the above script seems to work fine. At least it displays just fine when loading the php page in the browser.

**But when I make an ajax call with this script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "queries.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "",
        cache: false,
        success: function(result)
            {
                var cfkey = result[0];
                var user = result[1];
                alert("cfkey:" + cfkey + "user:" + user);
            }
    });
});
```

After loading this code, the chrome console states that the server returned with error 500.

**Again, what I am trying to accomplish:**

1. I would like to be able to make an ajax request for say, and ID, then get back all of that ID's corresponding data, (wrapped in Json - At least I think it needs to be..).
2. With the ajax script, I would like to be able to save the returned corresponding data to an input field in html.

**EDIT:**
Finally figured out that the problem I was discussing with Majid was with the SQL query.
key needed to be need to be wrapped in ` characters.

Comment: You're missing a `"` in your connection script, after `$pass`.

Comment: It was a typo when I took out my real password to paste the code here. The actual code on my server actually has the $pass = "password"; correctly stated in the php code. But thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you execute your query and the resultset is available in `$res` you could just build up your array, no need for a separate foreach:

```
$array = array(); // initialize
while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
  $array[] = array(
    'id'       => $row[0],
    'username' => $row[1],
    'password' => $row[2],
    'nick'     => $row[3],
    'addr'     => $row[4],
    'facebook' => $row[5],
    'twitter'  => $row[6],
    'linkedin' => $row[7],
    'youtube'  => $row[8]
  );
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

Also note that this way, your json will have keys, so to consume it you should change:

```
success: function(result) {
  var cfkey = result[0];
  var user = result[1];
  alert("cfkey:" + cfkey + "user:" + user);
}
```

To

```
success: function(result) {
  var cfkey = result.id;
  var user = result.username;
  alert("cfkey:" + cfkey + "user:" + user);
}
```

Or simply do

```
$.getJSON('queries.php', {cfkey: $("#cfkey").val()}, function(result) {
  // we have multiple results
  $.each(result, function(i,r) {
    console.log("cfkey:" + r.key + "user:" + r.username);
  });
});
```

Edit: added header as pointed out by @amurrell

Comment: Awesome advice! However, after inputing the code, php gives me:

Comment: Too many edits! Sorry. This shows its time for me to go to bed!

Comment: "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',' in /file/... on line 8

Comment: @user3259138, yes, I had errors in the code, the last edit should work hopefully ;)

Comment: Code: include 'db/dbcon.php';
//Start connection with SQL
$q = "SELECT * FROM `cfaddrbook`";
$res = $mysqli->query($q) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$sql]");
$array = array(); // initialize
while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
  $array[]['id'] = $row[0],
  $array[]['username'] = $row[1],
  // ... continue like this
}
echo json_encode($array);
$result->free();
$mysqli->close();

Comment: Still get a server returned with 500 error in the chrome console (for the ajax POST)

Comment: So now, the alert comes up, and states that the variables id and username are undefined?

Comment: What does firebug show you? You could check the returned result was rally a json object.

Comment: Oddly, it comes up as undefined. In the ajax call, what should "Data:" be set to?

Comment: I have not used the bare `ajax` method much. `getJSON` would be much easier to correctly configure for this use case.

Comment: @user3259138, added a `getJSON` alternative to the answer.

Comment: Used getJSON, and I still get the alert, but the values are still undefined, even after making all the edits you suggested? Its working, just not passing the data...?

Comment: What if you directly browse to `http://yoursite/path/to/queries.php`? What do you get?

Comment: I see valid json data printed on the web page.

Comment: Could you paste it here?

Comment: [{"key":"111111","username":"sbh","password":"2014","nick":"sbh","addr":"zzzzzzzzzz","facebook":"sbh","twitter":"sbh","linkedin":"sbh","youtube":"sbh"}]

Comment: Actually now it is: [{"key":"012910","username":"sbh0129","password":"2014","nick":"sbh","addr":"727 crest hill drive","facebook":"sbh","twitter":"sbh","linkedin":"sbh","youtube":"sbh"},{"key":"111111","username":"sbh","password":"2014","nick":"sbh","addr":"zzzzzzzzzz","facebook":"sbh","twitter":"sbh","linkedin":"sbh","youtube":"sbh"}]

Comment: Oh, OK then, we have the objects wrapped in an array -- another  edit will follow shortly ;)

Comment: @user3259138, check now.

Comment: Also, adding &username after the URL still shows all the JSON data, not specific data corresponding to it. So I am wondering if when the data is being passed back to the ajax query, it can't find its request?

Comment: That returned values. Now is there a way for me to say, "for key = "number" give me only the data that corresponds? Rather than it returning every key and username value?

Comment: If you have a `WHERE` clause in your query and still get multiple records, it only means you have multiple rows with that *id*, in other words, `id` is not unique/primary key.

Comment: Okay, so you are saying that ID cannot be unique or primary, is that correct?

Comment: I am saying you have not added the unique or primary index to `id` and as a result you have multiple rows in the table with the same `id`. On the other hand if the returned results have different ids then the previous hypothesis is not correct, and the issue is with your `WHERE` clause. Could you post your complete sql query?

Comment: ahhhh. So now to make it dynamic. How do I write the getJSON or ajax query to basically say, for  id = 111111, get me corresponding data? I think I have it figured out on the PHP side

Comment: `$.getJSON('url.php', { id: '11111' }, function(`... the rest.

Comment: Beware, whatever you use as the parameter name here you should match on PHP side. So: `$id=$_GET['id'];` and then `WHERE \`colname\` = '$id'`

Comment: So now I am doing: $.getJSON('queries.php', function(result) {
  var cfkey = document.getElementById("cfkey").value;
  $.each(result, { key: cfkey }, function(i,r) {
   console.log("user:" + r.username);
   
});
});

Comment: I have the input saved in that input field, and this method works in other functions. But when I send this request, it does not return the username...

Comment: Console says: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply' for line "$.each(result, { key: cfkey }, function(i,r) {"

Comment: 1. Wrong place add the object (should be *before* `function`) 2. No `var` keyword should be used. Correct code in the updated answer.

Comment: Okay fixed that. I needed to move the key : cfkey to the get JSON line. That was a stupid mistake. But now, the function works, but it returns both usernames in the database, I need it to return only one.. I am so close to this being done.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are expecting queries.php to return json (to your ajax) and thus you need content header types in your queries.php!

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: I added it under the "include" line, the console returned the 500 error again (for the ajax query). Did I add it to the wrong place?

Comment: You should probably put it before the include. On PHP's manual for [header](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), it says: 

Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Comment: It is now above the include line. Still makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need more useful error messages. Try adding the following lines at the beginning of your code.

error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: Added that, and now it just gives a bunch of php errors that make the script break.

Answer (score 0):

Your script that outputs JSON is writing several valid JSON strings (one for each database row), but they don't add up to a valid JSON file.  A JSON file should represent one JSON object.

If you want to pass an ID and get one database row back, you have to add that ID to the `data` part of your AJAX call, and modify queries.php to pass that id from its `$_POST` array into the `WHERE` part of your MySQL query.   Then, you'd only output one JSON-encoded object rather than many, which would be a valid JSON file.

(Alternately, you could `json_encode()` the entire `$rows` array rather than each `$row` individually if you want the whole table back.)

Also, if you `json_encode()` a string-indexed array in PHP, you read its properties in Javascript by name, not by index.  You've gone through the trouble of naming your keys in PHP, then switch back to trying to reference them by their 0-based index in Javascript.  You can pick one way or the other, but you can only pick one!

Comment: Your response is pretty much what I am trying to accomplish. Can you elaborate more on paragraphs 1 and 2 and 3, please?

Comment: So, all of it ...   If you set `data` to `{ id : 1 }`, then in PHP `$_POST['id']` will be `1`.  For now though, just hardcode the MySQL query to `SELECT * FROM cfaddrbook WHERE id = 1` (pick an existing id number, though) and you'll see that you get valid JSON back.  In your success handler, change `result[0]` to `result.id` and `result[1]` to `result.username`, and it should all work the way you want.  You should be able to figure it out from there with a little more experimentation.  Good luck!

Comment: After adding the WHERE id = 1 line, in my case WHERE key = 111111, it spits quite a few errors out. if I take it way, no more errors when displaying the php page.

Comment: Also, adding &username after the URL still shows all the JSON data, not specific data corresponding to it. So I am wondering if when the data is being passed back to the ajax query, it can't find its request?