# json lint removing spaces between words

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm retrieving data from a mysqli database using jquery post and a php file. One of my database fields is medium text. I'm retrieving the data as json. When I put the json data into json lint, I get:

```
Parse error on line 92:
...e said to himself, "Iwanttoknowmoreabout
-----------------------^
Expecting '}', ':', ',', ']'
```

...and I notice that json lint has removed the spaces between some of the words. Here is my php code:

```
require_once ('constants.php');
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}
$qNations = "SELECT b.Country, a.CountryCode, a.population, a.GDP, a.Income_level, b.Name, b.Age, b.Occupation, b.Origin, b.Neighborhood, b.FromHome, b.Video, b.PersonImage, b.CountryImage, b.WorldImage, b.Image2, b.Image3, b.Image4, b.Image5, b.Image6, b.Notes FROM countries a, people b where a.CountryID = b.CountryID order by a.Country";
$result = $db->query($qNations);

$numrecords = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$count = 0;
$strResults = '{"people": [';
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $count++;
    $story = $row['Notes'];

    $strResults .= '{
                        "country":"' . $row['Country'] . '",
                        "countryCode":"' . $row['CountryCode'] . '",
                        "population":"' . $row['population'] . '",
                        "GDP":"' . $row['GDP'] . '",
                        "income_level":"' . $row['Income_level'] . '",
                        "name":"' . $row['Name'] . '",
                        "age":"' . $row['Age'] . '",
                        "occupation":"' . $row['Occupation'] . '",
                        "origin":"' . $row['Origin'] . '",
                        "neighborhood":"' . $row['Neighborhood'] . '",
                        "story":"' . $story . '"
                    }';
    if ($count < $numrecords) { //only add a comma if there are more records to go
        $strResults .= ',';
    }
}
$strResults .= ']}';

$db->close();
echo $strResults;
```

What's the best way to format and/or return a medium text database field in json?

Comment: Don't manually encode your json, dump everything in an array and use `echo json_encode($your_array);` at the very end of your script. And make sure no other output is generated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to: Properly use PHP to encode data into JSON format, and request the data with jquery/ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491910/how-to-properly-use-php-to-encode-data-into-json-format-and-request-the-data-w)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. You never should build JSON yourself. You build a **NATIVE** php data structure, then use `json_encode()` to translate it for you.

That means instead of building a json string, you build a PHP array instead:

```
$data = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Remember that JSON is basically just Javascript code. You have to build syntactically valid Javascript, which means escaping any internal quotes:

```
var name = 'Miles O'Brien'; /// what you're building - an unterminated string
var name = 'Miles O\'Brien'; // what you SHOULD have built.
```

Comment: or simply in 1 line `echo json_encode($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));`

Comment: @Marc B: How do you escape internal quotes?

Comment: you don't. json_encode() takes care of all of that for you. PHP data goes in, json comes out. And it WILL be valid json.

Comment: I'm using your syntax, but now json lint is throwing the error, "Unexpected token" and not giving me a line number.

Comment: Then your script is probably outputting something else. e.g. a php warning stuffed into the output stream will also introduce a json syntax error. Your script can't output anything EXCEPT json.

Comment: I'm not seeing a warning. I'm using your code from above. If I take out the Notes field, I get valid json. When I put the Notes field back in, I get invalid json. The Notes field has html in it and is a medium text field, so it's pretty long.